# Building opencv 3.1, cannot find libpython although it is there

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda

I am building opencv 3.3.1 from source on CentOS.

```
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -DWITH_IPP=OFF -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/mydir ..
```

I have python version 2.7.13 installed in anaconda. I have configure the enrironment vars with regarding to anaconda. After I run cmake, the output shows that it has found the python related path under anaconda, messages like these:

```
    -   Python 2:
    --     Interpreter:                 /anaconda/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.13)
    --   Python (for build):            /anaconda/bin/python2.7
    --     Pylint:                      /anaconda/bin/pylint (ver: 1.6.4, checks: 110)
```

But it could not find these options:
        --     Libraries:
        --     numpy:
        --     packages path:

So finally it did not build python2.

I searched on my anaconda installation, these files are are all there. It is just that cmake cannot find them.  Then I suppose I can let cmake find them by setting the environment variables. So I added these lines in my .bashrc

```
    export PATH=/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/anaconda/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/anaconda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    export PYTHONPATH=/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

I run ldconfig, logout and login, clear build directory and run cmake again. Unfortunately, it still cannot find these option.

So what is wrong here?

Comment: why not just use conda to install it? https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3

Comment: or download the wheel file and install using pip? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

Comment: I do not know if the opencv version installed with pip has cuda support. But since I cannot install without pip successfully I have to try it.

Comment: Didn't realize you're going for the CUDA supported version.

Comment: Since I cannot solve problem with building from source. I take you suggestion, just ignore the issue of cuda support. Opencv  will not be heavily used in my python code, so maybe it is not a big deal.